# compileStatement throws Exception

Tags: android, sqlite

I recently met a problem while writing simple app on Android. Problem seems to appear every time I put '?' into query:

```
SQLiteStatement statement = db.compileStatement("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ?");
statement.bindString(1, "TableName");
statement.execute();
```

I got exception:

> E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "?": syntax error
>
> E/APP_LOG: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "?": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ?

Everything works fine if You replace '?' by TableName:

```
SQLiteStatement statement = db.compileStatement("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TableName");
statement.execute();
```

Does anyone know why I get this error? I've read it's because incorrect spaces (0xA0 instead of 0x20) but that wasn't it.

Comment: You can not use placeholder for table or column names

Comment: That was it, thank You